# Installing and Using Python Packages using Reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate

First I install miniconda...

```
reticulate::install_miniconda()
```

Then Check to see if Pandas and bcpandas are installed...

```
> py_module_available("pandas")
[1] FALSE
> py_module_available("bcpandas")
[1] FALSE
```

ok so next step is to install them!

```
py_install(envname = "C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\r-reticulate", packages="pandas")
py_install(envname = "C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\r-reticulate", packages="bcpandas")
```

Then Check to see if Pandas and bcpandas are installed...

```
> py_module_available("pandas")
[1] TRUE
> py_module_available("bcpandas")
[1] FALSE
```

Only pandas is available. Why ?!

Some points...

1.) I think py_config shows I'm in the correct folder

```
> py_config()
python:         C:/Users/xxxxxx/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/xxxxxx/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/xxxxxx/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.11 (default, Aug  5 2020, 19:41:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/xxxxxx/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.4
```

2.) I can see that the package bcpandas is available in the folder in question... C:/Users/xxxxxx/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/

3.) Ive tried various combinations of uninstalling & reinstalling RStudio, Miniconda, Tried the Devtools version of reticulate, tried creating a new conda folder using condainstall instead of py_install... Whatever I do I cannot seem to be able to access bcpandas using reticulate.

This has been really driving me totally mad today... Please help for the sake of my sanity!